# Batch GET requests in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, get, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm running AFNetworking GET requests in a loop. The "codeArray" has 8000 odd elements. However, AFNetworking makes only about ~1000 requests and stops abruptly. Anyone know what the problem could be? Is there a way I can make sure AFNetworking makes all the server calls without being interrupted?

```
for(NSString *station in codeArray)
{
     [self getLocationForStation:station
                    success:^(NSDictionary *response) {


                    } fail:^{

                    }];
}
```

The function that makes the GET calls using AFNEtworking looks like

```
- (void)getLocationForStation:(NSString *)stationCode
                  success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success fail: (void (^)())fail
{
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.in/station-details/%@.json", stationCode];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
url = [url URLByAppendingQueryString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_=%f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]]];

IRCTCHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [IRCTCHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:[url absoluteString] parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         success(responseObject);
     }     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

         //        NSLog(@"Failure!!");
     }];
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the error description? There may be a limit on the number of connections the server allows.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes! 8000 is a lot of simultaneous requests! That's almost over 9000!!!! I would throttle your requesting instead of figuring out why you can't do 8000 at the same time.

Luckily, NSOperationQueue makes that relatively easy to do for asynchronous operations. Here is a page that has a nice summary of how to do this: [Concurrent Operations Demystified](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent%5Foperations/)

Comment: Great. I'll look into throttling the requests.

Comment: I would guess they might be using some queue mechanism internally already, but maybe not! This will surely work though.